which electrode is better when calculating seeback coefficient of a 2D semiconductor? bulk metal electrodes or semiconductor material itself
I would like to calculate the seeback coefficient of a 2D semiconductor.
I am thinking,
If I use bulk metallic electrodes, the semicondutor itself is not heated because transiesta can only put electrodes into heat bath. And this is not consistent with the physics of seeback effect.
If I use semiconductor as the electrodes, it is consistent with the physics of seeback effect,but this brings us back to some of the issues I mentioned earlier siesta: Are the results reliable if I use semiconductors as electrodes with long screening layers?.
Any suggestions will be appreciated!
